# How to test if a username is a member of a posix group?

Tags: php

On the system that I'm running PHP, I have a username `foo` and a posix group `bar`. In my PHP script, how can I test whether the username `foo` is a member of the posix group `bar`?

Comment: whatever you tried please paste here

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```
$user_name  = 'foo';
$group_name = 'bar';
$group_info  = posix_getgrnam($group_name);
if (in_array($user_name, $group_info['members'])) {
  echo "{$user_name} is a member of {$group_name}";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, on my system when I run `groups jack`, it prints `jack : users www-data sudo`, but when I call `posix_getgrnam('www-data')` it returns an empty "members" array. In PHP is there a way to get the list of groups given a user, vs. the list of members given a group?

Comment: @user916968 What does `cat /etc/group | grep www-data` give you?